# null variable in a .bat, window batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I don't find how to set a null variable in a .bat on windows.

on linux I would do:

```
var=""
echo $var2/${var3}_brain_mask${var}.nii.gz
```

and then I have as results

> var2/var3_brain_mask.nii.gz

but if I do similar stuff on windows I have:

```
set var=""
echo %var2%/%var3%_brain_mask%var%.nii.gz
```

and as results

> var2/var3_brain_mask"" .nii.gz

the var variable is set at the beginning of the .bat, changed by the user, and I'ld like to be able to set it as empty variable by default as I do on linux.

does anyone has an idea how to do that ?

Comment: In cmd you undefine a var just setting it to nothing, without quotes. Doing your way, instead of undefining, you are defining a var which is started with **"**. So use this: **set var=** (without any trailing spaces/invisible chars after).

Comment: If I do that, then my echo looks like: trucmuch%var%.nii.gz as var is not recognize as a variable

Comment: Which Windows do you use?

Comment: I am working on windows 7

Comment: Did you type this in the CMD window by hand or did you try these exact 2 lines in a `.bat` or `.cmd` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on `Windows 8.1` and `Windows 10`
Simply place the opening `"` before `var`

```
set "var="
echo %var2%/%var3%_brain_mask%var%.nii.gz
```

Note!

```
set var=
```

and

```
set "var="
```

Will both work, it is however better to always use the latter as it will ensure there are no trailing whitespace captured in the variable which will result in issues with your output

Also, as demonstrated, from `cmdline` the output will differ from `batchfile`.

Comment: Yes, I did in Windows 7.

Comment: @FatalBulletHit which is what we want yes.

Comment: It seams @FatalBulletHit hit the point. Win7/8/10 may be equal, it depends on using bat or typing in command-line.

Comment: `set var=` works just as well (just be careful to not have trailing spaces on that line.

Comment: @LS_dev Yes, I know that, but the tag is `batch-file` specific.

Comment: thanks, I forgot to mention that I am working on windows 7.

Comment: @Joey Hence why I ALWAYS use double quotes to set variables :)

Comment: @p.deman then it should still work. You tagged batch file, are you running from cmdline?

Comment: Hi thanks, yes I use batch file, but tried your solution within cmdline ... sorry. didn't expect it change anything.

Comment: @p.deman Yes, so in batch file, `set var=` will also work BUT, it is always best to use double quotes to ensure that there are no trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Windows 10:

`SET var1= & ECHO 123 %var1% abc`,

`SET "var2=" & ECHO 123 %var2% abc` and

`ECHO 123 %var3% abc` will output: `123  abc` if in a `.bat` or `.cmd` file.

If typed in a CMD window by hand, each ouput would be: `123 %varN% abc` (where `N` stands for `1`, `2` and `3` accordingly).

---

`SET var4="" & ECHO 123 %var4% abc` will output `123 "" abc` in a `.bat` or `.cmd` file.

However, when typed in by hand in a CMD window the output will be `123 %var4% abc`, BUT: typing `ECHO 123 %var4% abc` afterwards will output `123 ""  abc`.

Comment: Ok, this seams to be the issue. You're right, in Win7 also.